# Slowing-down Function Based on Remainders as Powers of a constant

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series, fractions

I want to formalize an idea of a function where each $x$ distance traveled by the function divides into the prior distance leaving a remainder that is always a power of a constant.

For instance, if we take this constant to be 1 half, and the distance to be $S$, then $S_1/S_2=1+0.5^{1}$, and $S_2/S_3=1+0.5^{2}$, and so on, depending on how you index it and such. (at $S_1$, $y=1$, at $S_2$, $y=2$, and onward.)

**For clarity**, it seems that, $S_{1.5}/S_{2.5}$ ought to equal $1+0.5^{1.5}$

I want the function to be simple and continuous but have not had luck finding it. So, I'd be happy for inputs.

Comment: The problem is that "consecutive integers" are *discrete* so that your function **cannot** be continuous.

Comment: @user247327 I'm not sure I understand you; maybe I did not phrase my question as well as I ought to have?

Comment: @user247327 In short, I just want it to hit these values, it does not have to jump between them without changing. In other words, it can be raised to the power of 1.3 at the correct point and so on..... I meant consecutive relative to the points I was referring to.

Comment: Then there are infinitely many functions that will do that.  You will need to specify what you want to happen between integer values of x in order to determine a single such function.

Comment: @user247327 between integer values, I want it to follow the same trend seen at integer values (I don't want fluctuations), so it would probably resemble some kind of hyperbola. In other words, it should draw a smooth curve between all such integer points. Thank you. PS; let me know if you need more clarity.

Comment: For instance, $S_{1.5}/S_{2.5}$ ought to equal, if I'm reasoning correctly $1+0.5^{1.5}$ Does that make sense of it?